# C# Exceptions Not Being Handled

Tags: c#, debugging, error-handling

The following code is called via the browser and if an exception occurs that exception is never caught by the 'Try Catch' but instead the exception is reported to the screen.  I have tried running without debug as well as turning off CLR errors.  Any suggestions would be appreciated:

```
   public string GetUrl(string url)
    /*Grab remote page */
    {

        string target = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        StreamReader streamReader = null;
        try
        {

        httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

       streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true);

                target = streamReader.ReadToEnd();



        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:GetUrl()");
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", e.Status);
        } 
        finally
        {
            streamReader.Close();
                response.Close();

        }

        return target;


    }
```

Comment: which line do you get the exception? did you debug? if you get it at finally block where you close the reader it wont catch it.

Comment: First exception occurs immediately after the try

Comment: streamReader can be null on your finally block which would throw another exception if you get a 404.

Comment: what is the url string?

Answer (score 1):

You are only catching webexceptions, any other exception is not caught.

It can throw more exceptions see here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry Philip your suggestion really made no difference try  catch (Exception e).

Answer (score 0):

Add one more catch block  before finally block and trap base Excaption. It will catch all type of error occurred and not caught in earlier catch blocks.

Comment: Made no difference Anup:

Comment: What is the exception reported to the screen?